# r converting a column in json format that has lines with different structure

Tags: json, r

I got a table that was generated using a psql query. There is a column in this data table that is in JSON format which I need to extract and create new columns with this data. There are 172 lines in the data and some of the lines in this JSON column has a different structure. I tried many procedures and I can't find any simple and good solution. Does anybody has any idea how I can do this ?

```
reviewdata

         Id      QuestionId              Answer(JSON)
[1,]   1234             456                    "45900"
[2,]   1234             234           "{\"userId\":3034,\"userName\":\"Mr Jay\",\"teamId\":555}"
[172,] 1234             765           "{\"userId\":123,\"userName\":\"Mr Liu\",\"teamId\":098}"
```

Comment: Did you see [`jsonlite::fromJSON()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html)?

Comment: I tried and didn't work because some of the Json lines are in a different structure. I tried rjson, jsonlite and RJSONIO and I can't really find a good solution for this! :(

Comment: can you update your question with the output of `dput(head(reviewdata))`. This will give us the actual data for us to use.